# python: How to adjust plotly plot width on the basis of number of elements in x-axis

Tags: python, pandas, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I am trying to plot a graph on dash with a dropdown with date on x-axis and Release on y-axis like a Roadmap, so if a user selects his desired "Release", the graph will be updated. My problem is, when there are a huge number of "Dates", the graph looks something like this:
[image]

My questions are:

1. How can I say that if the amount of values on x-axis is greater than a particular number, increase the plot width to for eg. 2000 and keep the default width=1000.

   style={'overflowY': 'scroll', 'width': 1000}

   fig.update_layout(
   autosize=False,
   width=1000,
   height=400)
2. what can I do so that the text on scatter points don't overlap each other to avoid overcrowding?
3. In some cases, there are multiple y-axis value for an individual x-axis (Date) value, due to which the plot just takes 1 point on x axis and puts all the values of y-axis there:

[image]

Comment: "Why does my script produce this output?" - Are we supposed to guess what the script and the input is? Please provide an MCVE. And why is this tagged matplotlib - the output looks like plotly.

Answer (score 0):

for question 2 (what can I do so that the text on scatter points don't overlap each other to avoid overcrowding?) use turtle.Pen(write, size(your size))(DATE) you will need to change the DATE to the date you want but it will still work